# "My Computer" Icon does not show a right click menu

Tags: windows-registry, windows-server-2003

My OS is Windows Server 2003.

After modifying

```
My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\
ProfileList\ProfilesDirectory Reg_Sz Default
```

to the value

```
%SystemDrive%\Documents and Settings
```

the *My Computer* icon does not give me any right click menu, or anything from "My Documents: Open, Explore, Save folder listing to file..., Search..., Manage, Services, Create a shortcut, Rename, Properties."

I would like to have these menus back. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you change the value to back to what it was before.  Does the menu reappear?

Comment: The change to this register key is enabling me to redirect the User Profiles to a D:\ drive, I don't want to change it back.